# How to dynamically select columns in Oracle? is this possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data set:

```
NAME     2012        2013       2014         2015        2016         2017      2018         2019
JOHN      180          185       192          205         199          198       193          null
MIKE      190          191       191          195         195          null       195          195
```

Currently i have the below query:

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(COALESCE("2019", 0),
             COALESCE("2018", 0),
             COALESCE("2017", 0),
             COALESCE("2016", 0),
             COALESCE("2015", 0),
             COALESCE("2014", 0),
             COALESCE("2013", 0),
             COALESCE("2012", 0)) AS max_weight
   , LEAST  (COALESCE("2019", 0),
             COALESCE("2018", 0),
             COALESCE("2017", 0),
             COALESCE("2016", 0),
             COALESCE("2015", 0),
             COALESCE("2014", 0),
             COALESCE("2013", 0),
             COALESCE("2012", 0)) AS max_weight
   , PERSON_NAME
  FROM yourTable;
```

Is there a way to alter te above query so that it asks for the desired year, uses that as an input parameter and only grabs data for that partciular year + the 5 years prior?

So for example: If i inputed 2017 , it would return the following result:

```
  PERSON_NAME         MIN_WEIGHT           MAX_WEIGHT
   JOHN                  185                  205
   MIKE                  190                  195
```

Is there any way to do this? (similar to a parameter in a function / stored procedure)?  I was thinking of substituting the year #s with some sort of parameter and inputting that ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` your columns into rows, so that you can apply aggregates like `MAX` on them.

Like so,

```
with test_data (NAME, "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019" ) AS (
SELECT 'JOHN', 180, 185, 192, 205, 199, 198, 193, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIKE', 190, 191, 191, 195, 195, null, 195, 195 FROM DUAL )
SELECT * 
FROM test_data
UNPIVOT ( 
  weight FOR year IN ("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
);
```

> ```
> +------+------+--------+
> | NAME | YEAR | WEIGHT |
> +------+------+--------+
> | JOHN | 2012 |    180 |
> | JOHN | 2013 |    185 |
> | JOHN | 2014 |    192 |
> | JOHN | 2015 |    205 |
> | JOHN | 2016 |    199 |
> | JOHN | 2017 |    198 |
> | JOHN | 2018 |    193 |
> | MIKE | 2012 |    190 |
> | MIKE | 2013 |    191 |
> | MIKE | 2014 |    191 |
> | MIKE | 2015 |    195 |
> | MIKE | 2016 |    195 |
> | MIKE | 2018 |    195 |
> | MIKE | 2019 |    195 |
> +------+------+--------+
> ```

Once you have the data unpivoted like that, you can use aggregate functions and `GROUP BY` to get the results you're looking for:

```
with test_data (NAME, "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019" ) AS (
SELECT 'JOHN', 180, 185, 192, 205, 199, 198, 193, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIKE', 190, 191, 191, 195, 195, null, 195, 195 FROM DUAL )
SELECT name, 
       min(weight) min_weight,
       max(weight) max_weight, 
       max(year) keep ( dense_rank last order by weight desc, year asc ) min_weight_year,
       max(year) keep ( dense_rank first order by weight desc, year asc ) max_weight_year
FROM test_data
UNPIVOT ( 
  weight FOR year IN ("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
)
GROUP BY name;
```

> ```
> +------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
> | NAME | MIN_WEIGHT | MAX_WEIGHT | MIN_WEIGHT_YEAR | MAX_WEIGHT_YEAR |
> +------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
> | JOHN |        180 |        205 |            2012 |            2015 |
> | MIKE |        190 |        195 |            2012 |            2015 |
> +------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
> ```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I guess I should've been more clear with my question, what i was wondering was ... is there a way i can create a view/materialized view that asks the user for the year desired (i.e. 2017) and then ''dynamically' returns the min/max of 2017 data + the 5 years prior

Comment: so for example, lets say i do : select * from view. IS there a way to have select * from view where year = 2017 returns the min/max of 2012-2017? (and 2018 returning 2013-2018)?

Comment: Yes.  Make the basic `UNPIVOT` (the 1st query I gave you) the definition of the view.  Then `SELECT ... FROM the_view WHERE year BETWEEN '2012' and '2017'`.  I think I'm missing something important about what you are after.  Like you want something that uses dynamic SQL to change the column names based on the input.  But what are you planning to do about your unspecified "data set" when 2020 rolls around?

Comment: Thanks you're right, sorry I didn't get it the first time. I'll probably have to change the code... unless you had any other suggestions? haha

Comment: My suggestion would be to store the data as rows of (name, year, weight) in the first place.  The structure you had is convenient for users to view the data, but not convenient for programs to query or manipulate the data.  Make that database structure convenient for programs and put user-readability concerns into the user interface layer.

Comment: yeah i agree unfortuantely the data structure is non negotiable :(